# How to update a Svelte store in the server part of my SPA?

Tags: node.js, store, svelte, sapper, svelte-3

I want my Svelte SPA to interact with some data from a DB. For this, I used Sapper, so I can open the connection to DB in the server.js, and listen to it through its pub/sub mechanism. How can I then parse the message to my reactive store? here, channelArray is just a writable([]) imported from a '/.store.js'
With this code, I can parse to the App data to the store, but only when initialized?

```
// server.js


import sirv from 'sirv';
import polka from 'polka';
import compression from 'compression';
import * as sapper from '@sapper/server';
import { channelArray, chNum } from './components/store.js';

const { PORT, NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const dev = NODE_ENV === 'development';



polka() // You can also use Express
    .use(
        compression({ threshold: 0 }),
        sirv('static', { dev }),
        sapper.middleware()
    )
    .listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) console.log('error', err);
    });



const Redis = require('ioredis');
const chpattern = "vac:*";
const sub = new Redis();


sub.psubscribe(chpattern);  
sub.on("pmessage", function (pattern, channel, message) { 
      console.log(`REDIS updated, number of channels`);
      chNum.subscribe(value => {console.log(value)});
      console.log(`Channel ${channel} Received msg: ${message}`);
  var ch = parseInt( channel.slice(4) );
  //if (ch >= 0 && ch < chNum ) { 
  if (ch >= 0 ) { 
      console.log('REDIS updated');
          channelArray[ch].value = message;
          channelArray[ch].lastupdate = Date.now();
  } 
});
```

And the relevant part of the index.html

```
<script>
       import Ctrlbox from '../components/Ctrlbox.svelte';
       import { channelArray, chNum } from '../components/store.js';
       import Blinkbox from '../components/blinkbox.svelte'

       let ch = 0;

       const addChannel = () => {
        $channelArray = [...$channelArray, {
        id: ch++,
            value: 0,
            lastupdate: new Date()
        }];
       };


       const box = [0,1,2];

       for (var i=0; i< box.length; i++) {
           addChannel();
       }
       chNum.set(ch);


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

While this on the backend

```
import { channelArray, chNum } from './components/store.js';
```

technically works, it does not do what you expect. The imported `channelArray` on the backend is not the same as on the frontend, they're different instances of `writable` and there's no connection or binding between them.

You'll need to add some sort of communication between front- and backend. AJAX requests or socket io, whatever suits best. Some REST API is probably the easiest solution.

I went through this with an electron app, but there I can use the built in IPC so that the frontend and backend can exchange data.

Comment: Exactly! I realize that: if I update my writable on the frontend, say, put 3 items in the array, the server.js doesnt know. I have this app working in Electron too, but wanted to be running light on an already existing browser (will need many apps working in the same PC and dont want several electron Apps).

Comment: May I ask: would it be possible to have the same channelArray on both frontend and backend using the Svelte context API? Dont know if I could use that feature inside my server.js

Comment: It is not. You run two different javascript environment. One is the nodejs engine, the server (backend) and the other one runs inside your browser. One runs the backend code, the other one the svelte application (the bundle.js script). There is no link or channel between them. The server has no access to the data inside the browser and vice versa. A very, very common solution is a REST API. Routing on the backend and many use axios on the client. JSON.stringify and JSON.parse and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you directly manipulating the store. I don't think that is the best approach. According to the [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#writable) a `writable` has a `set` and `update` method. You use `set` when you want to change the value of the variable and don't care about the previous value. `update` is used if you care about the previous value, so for incrementing for example.

It seems that `update` would fit your use case, as you seem to care about the previous state. So I would propose this:

```
 const addChannel = () => {
   channelArray.update(oldState => ([
     ...oldState,
     { id: ch++,
     value: 0,
     lastupdate: new Date() }
   ]));
 };
```

Comment: I got the same with update. Seems like the server doesnt see any change on the store. Anyhow, my wonder is if this approach: interacting with the store in the node.js server, is possible.

Comment: I guess then you would have to move the update function also to the server and execute it there when the client sends you a message to which you respond with the updated store value. Sounds complicated.

Comment: `$channelArray= ...` is the correct syntax. It's a shorthand for working with writables.